# Passing dynamically allocated 2d array to a function

Tags: c

The following code is not working correctly.  I'm getting a segfault when I run the program.  I ran my program through gdb and found out that the error is occuring in the fillArrays(int**,int) function.

GDB is displaying the following parameters for fillArrays(int**,int):

```
fillArrays (arrays=0x0,numArrays=3)
```

Here is the source code to my program

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc and free */

#define MULTIPLIER          1
#define SMALL               10
#define BIG                 20

void allocateSmallArrays(int **arrays,int numArrays) {
    int index,freeIndex;
    int outerIndex,innerIndex;
    arrays = malloc(numArrays*sizeof(int*));
    if(arrays == NULL) {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(index = 0;index < numArrays;index++) {
        arrays[index] = malloc(SMALL*sizeof(int));
        if(arrays[index] == NULL) {
            printf("out of memory\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

void fillArrays(int **arrays,int numArrays) {
    int outerIndex,innerIndex;
    for(outerIndex = 0;outerIndex < numArrays;outerIndex++) {
        for(innerIndex = 0;innerIndex < SMALL;innerIndex++)
            arrays[outerIndex][innerIndex] = 0;
    }
}

void deallocateSmallArrays(int **arrays,int numArrays) {
    int index;
    for(index = 0;index < numArrays;index++)
        free(arrays[index]);
    free(arrays);
}

int main(void) {
   int numArrays  = (3 * MULTIPLIER);
   int **arrays = 0;

   allocateSmallArrays(arrays,numArrays);
   fillArrays(arrays,numArrays);
   deallocateSmallArrays(arrays,numArrays);

   arrays = 0;

   return 0;
}
```

I was under the assumption that since arrays was allocated in allocateSmallArrays, that passing it through fillArrays would 0 out the allocated arrays and then deallocate in the last function.  How do I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `allocateSmallArrays` changes **its own copy of the `arrays` pointer**. So the result of the `malloc` is lost and after the function is done, in the caller `arrays` is still 0. You could:

- Pass a triple pointer `int ***arrays` and do to `*arrays` everything you're doing to `arrays`
- **Return the pointer instead of void**

A [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html) deals with this very subject.